# How to bind a angular ng-click event on after lnserted HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am developing `rails application where angularjs` use in it.

I am facing one problem which i can't understand. Angularjs works fine in all events but i have one module where `new html load after page scroll` and one another where `push new html into` existing html on page.

On new html inserted in page, one button in new html where i would like to `ng-click event bind` with it so when user click on that button i want to procedure.

I tried it but not getting how to bind with button because on loaded html bind easily but in new html not bind.

How to bind on that new HTML button?

Any one have a idea?

Thanks

Comment: it would help you to show us what you did to add the html... in theory you shouldn't insert html by yourself. It should be angular who create new html

Comment: Yes, you are right.. it is easy to show if code here... but its some confusion in code.. so not explain using code...just want to know how to bind ng-click event on any element

Comment: if you insert html that has angular directives or expressions in it you need to use `$compile()`

Comment: have you tried $compile()

Comment: No any time use it. How to?

Comment: But my HTML does not insert through directive. Its insert using jQuery then how to bind angular event?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the html in order to get the binds.

Inject $compile in your controller and:

```
var cHtml = $compile("<button ng-click='doSomething()'>Click me!</button>")($scope);
```

Then you can add that html using element.append() or jquery

Comment: The use of $compile is correct, but I suggest putting this piece of logic into a directive. Directive are the components that interact with the DOM, not controllers.

Comment: Is there a reason why the () don't match up? Am I missing something?

Comment: What about if I'm inserting a link that should have `ng-click` using optimizely or some similar testing tool? Obviously I don't have access to any of these variables (`$compile` or `$scope`)